# Create a Parameter that is a Varying Function

Tags: java, scala, java-8, metaprogramming, covariance

In Java and Scala, how would I do the following:

I want to be able to pass a function into a function as a parameter where the function parameter is somewhat varying. For example, this is what I am locked into now in Java:

```
public void doSomething(Object object, Action1<Object> function) {
    function.call(object); 
} 

public void doOtherThing(Object obj) {
    System.out.println(obj);
}

doSomething("hello", this::doOtherThing);
```

This is what I want to be able to do:

```
public void doSomethingFancy(Object object, <Some Function Type Here> function) {
    function.call(object);
}

public void doFancyThing(Object obj1, String str1, List list1) {
   // do stuff
}
public void doFancyThing2(Object obj1, RandomObj rObj, Integer int1) {
   // do stuff
}
...
doSomething("hello", this::doFancyThing);
doSomething("hello", this::doFancyThing2);
```

Basically I want the input function to have a variable type of input parameters. ActionN won't work because that would be passing a object array into my `doFancyThing` method and that obviously doesn't compile.

Comment: Make a custom interface.

Comment: Over load the method signature? do you have a specific set of input parameters?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Any interface that has exactly one abstract method is a functional interface, and can thus be implemented using a lambda function or method reference.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public class MyFancyInterface {
    void call(Object obj1, String str1, List list1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about,

An executor interface:

```
public interface Executor<T> {
    void execute(T source); 
}
```

A simple executor:

```
public class SimpleExecutor implements Executor<String> {

    @Override
    public void execute(String source) {
        System.out.println(source);
    }

}
```

A fancy executor:

```
public class FancyExecutor implements Executor<Object>{

    @Override
    public void execute(Object source) {
       System.out.println("doing some fancy stuff");        
    }

}
```

An Action:

```
public class Action {

    public <T> void doSomething(T source, Executor<T> executor) {
        executor.execute(source);
    }

}
```

And finally:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Action action = new Action();
    action.doSomething("hey there", new SimpleExecutor());
    action.doSomething(new Object(), new FancyExecutor());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your definitions, `doSomethingFancy("hello", this::doFancyThing);` (I assume you wanted this instead of `doSomething("hello", this::doFancyThing);` in the second example) should call `doFancyThing("hello")`, which is impossible: it's missing two arguments! Similarly for `doSomethingFancy("hello", this::doFancyThing2);`, which calls `doFancyThing2("hello")`.

And if you think about it a bit, you should find that changing the definition of `doSomethingFancy` will not help: there is just nothing it can do (except trivial things like returning `null`, `object`, `function.hashCode()`, etc.). So when the language doesn't let you even declare it, that's a good thing.

Two actual possibilities:

1. Provide missing arguments as part of the function:

   ```
   public <T> void doSomething(T object, Action1<T> function) {
       function.call(object); 
   }

   doSomething("hello", x -> doFancyThing(x, "a", Collections.<Integer> emptyList()));
   doSomething("hello", x -> doFancyThing2(x, some other arguments));
   ```

   This works and it works great.
2. Use varargs to supply all parameters:

   ```
   public void doSomething(Action1<Object[]> function, Object... args) {
       function.call(object); 
   }

   doSomething(args -> doFancyThing((Object) args(0), (String) args(1), (List) args(2)), "hello", "a", Collections.<Integer> emptyList()));
   ```

   You could extract the `args -> doFancyThing((Object) args(0), (String) args(1), (List) args(2))` part to a generic method, so the calls would look like

   ```
   doSomething(toVarArgs(this::doFancyThing), "hello", "a", Collections.<Integer> emptyList()));
   ```

This is left as an exercise.